# Having trouble installing a CPAN module on Strawberry Perl running on Windows 7

Tags: perl, cpan

I've got Strawberry Perl installed on a Windows 7 system. Also have a MinGW installation located in C:\MinGW\msys\bin (where my make.exe resides). Strawberry is located in c:\Strawberry\Perl\bin.

I'm trying to install HTML::TableContentParser into a local library, and the script that installs the module fails with a "cannot find the path specified" error, and tells me to build manually, which I don't know how to do, and have been unable to find instructions that work. It always comes back to the makefile somehow.

Here's what I get when I run "cpan HTML::TableContentParser" from my c:\strawberry\perl\bin directory:

```
C:\Users\joel>cd c:\strawberry\perl\bin

c:\Strawberry\perl\bin>cpan HTML::TableContentParser
Loading internal null logger. Install Log::Log4perl for logging messages
CPAN: Storable loaded ok (v2.56_01)
Reading '\c\Users\joel\.cpan\Metadata'
  Database was generated on Mon, 15 May 2017 15:54:01 GMT
Running install for module 'HTML::TableContentParser'
CPAN: Digest::SHA loaded ok (v5.96)
CPAN: Compress::Zlib loaded ok (v2.07)
Checksum for \c\Users\joel\.cpan\sources\authors\id\S\SD\SDRABBLE\HTML-       TableContentParser-0.13.tar.gz ok
The system cannot find the path specified.
Uncompressed \c\Users\joel\.cpan\sources\authors\id\S\SD\SDRABBLE\HTML-TableContentParser-0.13.tar.gz successfully
Using Tar:/usr/bin/tar xf "HTML-TableContentParser-0.13.tar":
The system cannot find the path specified.
Couldn't untar HTML-TableContentParser-0.13.tar: child exited with value 1
CPAN: YAML loaded ok (v1.21)
  SDRABBLE/HTML-TableContentParser-0.13.tar.gz
  Had problems unarchiving. Please build manually
```

Comment: You'll be better off relying on the MinGW and various utilities bundled with Strawberry Perl rather than mixing tools from different origins. Also, installing manually just means `tar xvf HTML-TableContentParser-0.13.tar.gz; cd HTML-TableContentParser-0.13; perl Makefile.PL; make; make test; make install`

Comment: I'm not convinved you're running the right `cpan`. Do you get different results if you do `.\cpan.bat HTML::TableContentParser` instead?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I tried the manual steps, running make failed, I noticed the word 'dmake' in the output "dmake-style makefile, so I looked in the Strawberry\perl\bin folder, and saw a file there named dmake.exe. Tried running that and it worked, so I thought I was finally getting somewhere. But the next manual step "make test" failed, and now it's beginning to look like there's a problem with that, which brings me up to the second answer. How do I know I'm installing the right cpan module? I thought it would get the latest, greatest version. I haven't used CPAN with Strawberry before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

1. Do not use separate MinGW it already comes packed with Strawberry Perl. Make sure you have a recent version of Strawberry Perl.
2. Download the tar.gz for the perl module from any of the sites(Metacpan or Cpan).
3. Use winzip to unzip it which will give you all files extracted to a location.
4. Now open command prompt and change directory to the one where you extracted the tar.gz for the perl module.
5. Run the following commands then:

   - perl Makefile.pl
   - dmake
   - dmake test
   - dmake install

The command dmake test one is optional, if you get errors here try skipping to the next command and try using the module in your scripts. As many times the test fails does not means the module won't install or work properly. If there is error the module will give error in installation too.

Make sure you have the Makefile.pl file in the extracted directory. This will install the module without any issues.

I am assuming that you are working on a Windows system. Do let me know if you face any errors still.

Comment: Got errors on the dmake test step: some of my output followsTest Summary Report
-------------------
t/1.t (Wstat: 0 Tests: 10 Failed: 0)
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 34 tests but ran 10.
Files=1, Tests=10,  1 wallclock secs ( 0.09 usr +  0.00 sys =  0.09 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 1/1 test programs. 0/10 subtests failed.
dmake:  Error code 255, while making 'test_dynamic'

Comment: Did you first remove the path of your separately existing MinGW from your environment variables. I think it is still there ans this test is using that same MinGW which you have not the Strawberry perl one.

Comment: Also try skipping the test command and directly do a install. Skip dmake test and see if you are able to use that in your scripts.

Comment: Got it now, have a module installed. Did a --force install which put it in a local library (on my desktop), but failed on my laptop. Then found a tip on the cpan site which said to install and use cpanm (which I should have done first). That installed it on my laptop in the \strawberry\perl\site\lib folder. And I've run a Perl Cookbook program to test it. Works fine except that the cookbook program is obviously written for a different version of the website. But I see the table data moved into a data structure in the debugger. Thank you everyone.

Comment: @Mohit I think the answer needs to be updated since I found a statement saying the `dmake` was replaced by `gmake`